# Can't use square/js-jose (jose-jwe-jws) npm package in Typescript and Webpack project

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, cryptography, jose

I'm trying to use the library in my project, based on Typescript targeting es6 and using commonjs modules. The final output is produced using Webpack and targeting the web platform.

I've installed the dependency with `npm install --save jose-jwe-jws` and try to reference it in my code:

```
import {Jose} from "jose-jwe-jws";
...
let cryptographer = new Jose.WebCryptographer();
...
```

Everything compiles good, but when I run the result of webpack in my page, I've got an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Jose is not defined
```

What I'm missing?

Thank You